# npm script with $npm_package on folder with spaces in path

Tags: macos, shell, npm

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "folders": {
    "plugin": {
      "dist": "\"/Users/User/Google Drive/App/Dist/plugin\""
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "remove_shared_dist": "rm -rf $npm_package_folders_plugin_dist"
  }
}
```

I want to remove the following folder: `/Users/User/Google Drive/App/Dist/plugin`.
I've wrapped its path with `\"` to make the shell accept folder names with space; but it only prints

```
rm -rf $npm_package_folders_plugin_dist
```

and does absolutely nothing.
If I run `rm -rf "/Users/User/Google Drive/App/Dist/plugin"` in terminal - it removes the folder as expected.
I'm on macOS

Comment: I don't think this is the primary problem, but in shell syntax you should put double-quotes around the variable reference (i.e. `"remove_shared_dist": "rm -rf \"$npm_package_folders_plugin_dist\""`), and *not* in the variable's value (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables) for details).

Comment: tried that; unfortunately, in that case `npm run` environment doesn't recognise `$npm_package_folders_plugin_dist` as a variable, but as a string

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon Davisson's comment [hinted me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458483/4507580) to the right direction.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "folders": {
    "plugin": {
      "dist": "\"/Users/User/Google Drive/App/Dist/plugin\""
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "remove_shared_dist": "bash -c \"rm -rf $npm_package_folders_plugin_dist\""
  }
}
```